# Munin - apache_watch_ plugin, does not show any data in the graphs that shows activity for per vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, monitoring, ubuntu-10.04, virtualhost, munin

I am using Munin for monitoring my server.

I installed the apache_watch_ plugin so that i could see apache related activity. The graphs for **apache_accesses**, **apache_processes** and **apache_volume work** fine.

But the graphs for **Apache Documents served**, **Apache Input/output (bytes)**, **Apache Requests** don't show any activity in the graph. The important thing is that these graphs that don't show anything are supposed to show the data divided per vhosts.

I am on Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS (Lucid Lynx) and the munin version is 1.4.4.

One thing that I think may be the cause for issue is that I have a separate config file for every vhost, which are included in the main config. But I can't really figure out any solution.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There's a related question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/328851/apache-server-status-not-found-check-if-mod-status-is-enabled/328904#328904 With a solution which worked for me, plus some diagnostic steps you might find useful

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
% munin-node-configure --suggest | grep apache
apache_accesses            | no   | no [Port 80: Forbidden]                
apache_processes           | no   | no [Port 80: Forbidden]                
apache_volume              | no   | no [Port 80: Forbidden]
```

return ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to point these plugins to access the statuspage served by [mod_status](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_status.html), configured on one vhost.