# apache server-status not found. check if mod_status is enabled

Tags: mod-rewrite, ubuntu-10.04, munin, apache-2.2

I've enabled the `apache_` plugins on a munin node:
`ln -sv /usr/share/munin/plugins/apache_* /etc/munin/plugins/`

After restarting the node with `service munin-node restart` here are the errors I'm getting:

```
$ munin-node-configure --suggest 2>/dev/null | grep "apache\|Plugin\|------"
Plugin                     | Used | Suggestions                            
------                     | ---- | -----------                            
apache_accesses            | yes  | no [apache server-status not found. check if mod_status is enabled]
apache_processes           | yes  | no [apache server-status not found. check if mod_status is enabled]
apache_volume              | yes  | no [apache server-status not found. check if mod_status is enabled]
```

However `mod_status` is already enabled:

```
$ a2enmod status
Module status already enabled
```

And restarting apache doesn't make a difference.

If I try to run the plugins manually here is what I get (I read that getting a U is bad news so at least that is consistent).

```
$ munin-run apache_accesses --debug
# Processing plugin configuration from /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node
# Set /rgid/ruid/egid/euid/ to /110/65534/110 110 /65534/
# Setting up environment
# About to run '/etc/munin/plugins/apache_accesses'
accesses80.value U

$ munin-run apache_processes --debug
# Processing plugin configuration from /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node
# Set /rgid/ruid/egid/euid/ to /110/65534/110 110 /65534/
# Setting up environment
# About to run '/etc/munin/plugins/apache_processes'
busy80.value U
idle80.value U
free80.value U

$ munin-run apache_volume --debug
# Processing plugin configuration from /etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node
# Set /rgid/ruid/egid/euid/ to /110/65534/110 110 /65534/
# Setting up environment
# About to run '/etc/munin/plugins/apache_volume'
volume80.value U
```

**Does anybody know why I'm still getting the `server-status not found` message and how I can get rid of it?**

**Updated answer 1**

Shane's suggestion was correct about setting a request handler using `Location` and `SetHandler` in the apache site. For more information on `mod_status` please refer to [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html)

I could verify that `munin` was effectively making the appropriate requests by looking at `/var/log/apache2/access.log` where I was getting this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Nov/2011:07:24:15 +0000] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 404 7774 "-" "libwww-perl/5.834
```

In my case setting the `Location` wasn't enough as I am running a `Drupal` site and the `.htaccess` combined with `mod_rewrite` were rewriting the requests. To fix it, I had to add the following line to my `.htaccess`

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status  # <= added this line
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please note that this doesn't represent a security problem since access to `/server-status` is restricted to `127.0.0.1` in the apache site.

**Updated answer 2**

It appears that adding the `Location` to the apache site wasn't needed after all since this is already defined in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf`. Btw, should you want to add the `ExtendedStatus On` directive, that's in that file that you should do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like it's trying to actually make requests to the status module.  Do you have a proper config for the status location in your `VirtualHost`?  Something like this:

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Comment: Valid point indeed although in my case I also had to do some `mod_rewrite` work (see updated question with answer)

Answer (score 5):

I found solution from Many Ayromlou [on this site](http://nerdlogger.com/2012/02/17/getting-apache-mod_status-and-mod_info-to-play-nicely-with-wordpress/):

> The problem is that these .htaccess rules in wordpress take over server-info and server-status urls activated in apache’s config and return a page not found error.
> I came across numerous sites that suggested adding a rule like:
>
> ```
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
> ```
>
> This didn't work for me. I'm not sure if the multisite version of wordpress (which I'm using) is causing this. The rule that worked beautifully is the following:
>
> ```
>     RewriteRule ^(server-info|server-status) - [L]
> ```
>
> This rule stops the rewrite engine whenever server-info or server-status is parsed as part of the URL.

Comment: The nerdlogger site is no longer available.  The `RewriteRule ^(server-info|server-status) - [L]` may not work in every instance, even if placed right before the other RewriteRules.  Sometimes creating a separate VirtualHost stanza is easiest as in my answer at: https://serverfault.com/questions/291692/why-do-i-get-a-404-not-found-when-trying-to-get-server-status/648259?noredirect=1#comment1375397_648259

Answer (score 3):

I found out I could run

```
$ wget http://localhost/server-status?auto
```

but not

```
$ wget http://127.0.0.1/server-status?auto
```

The first one is hitting the default server, the second a virtual server.

So I explicitly added an apache section to `/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node`

```
[apache_*]
env.url   http://localhost:%d/server-status?auto
env.ports 80
```

and got my munin apache graphs.

Answer (score 1):

mod_status built into Apache web server to get server status from a web browser. With this module we can easily find out how well the server is performing. All reports are generated in a html format.

Step1. Check if status module is enabled or not
apache2ctl -M   or ls /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Step2. If not enabled, enable it by the command,

sudo a2enmod status

step3. Configure access,

Open /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/status.conf  and comment the lines,

```
        #<Location /server-status>
        #    SetHandler server-status
        #    Require local
        #Require ip 192.0.2.0/24
        #</Location>
```

And add the following line,

```
        <Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        </Location>
```

We can restrict the access of server status for particular IP’s in this configuration by editing ,
Allow from our_public_ipaddress   instead of    Allow from all

Save the status.conf  file .

Step4. Restart apache by the command,

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Step5. Check the server status page in browser

http://server-ip/server-status

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. Here's some more diagnostic steps. Try doing

```
munin-run apache_processes autoconf
```

That's a more direct way to see the same error "*no (no apache server-status on ports 80)*"

Now try doing

```
wget http://127.0.0.1/server-status?auto
```

For me that's giving *403 Forbidden*.

I was also seeing *'client denied by server configuration: /var/www/server-status'* in my main apache error log

You getting the same?

For me in fact Shane Madden's answer solved it.

Comment: Hi Harry, if you're having the same problem then please vote up the question as it increases the probability of getting answers.

Comment: Will do, just as soon as I have enough reputation to vote :-)

Answer (score 0):

If /server-status is forbidden only from 127.0.0.1 you can create VirtualHost configuration for 127.0.0.1 with following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin superadmin@somemail.com
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www>
      Options +FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

[Here is](http://druss.pp.ua/2014/12/fixed-apache-mod_status-server-status-forbidden-from-127-0-0-1/) more detailed explanation