# Munin Apache graphs have disappeared

Tags: apache-2.2, munin, graph

I'm running Apache2 and Munin on Ubuntu 12.04. All of my Munin graphs are showing up fine (cpu, memory, etc.), except for the Apache graphs.

The Apache graphs were working at one point, which you can see from this screenshot showing data from a few months ago: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukEuY.png. But now there's nothing there.

Apache itself is running fine, with lots of activity (website getting around 500,000 pageviews per month).

**UPDATE:**

Checked apache log, and found that munin's attempts to access server-status seemed to be getting redirected (notice 301):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2013:07:25:02 -0600] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 301 590 "-" "libwww-perl/6.03"
```

So followed the suggestion [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/328851/apache-server-status-not-found-check-if-mod-status-is-enabled) and added `RewriteRule ^(server-info|server-status) - [L]` to my .htaccess file. Now inspecting apache log I see attempts to access server-status are apparently successful (notice 200):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2013:07:40:01 -0600] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 200 781 "-" "libwww-perl/6.03"
```

**However: Munin Apache graphs are still blank.**

`wget http://127.0.0.1/server-status?auto` returns:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2013:07:35:01 -0600] "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1" 200 781 "-" "libwww-perl/6.03"
```

`munin-run apache_processes autoconf` returns:

```
Unknown service 'apache_processes'
```

Could that indicate a problem?

**Update 2:**

Well, looks like I didn't wait long enough after fixing the htaccess file... Munin graphs now seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue when I put a password for `/server-status` Location. So first of all you should check that you have `/server-status` location opened for `localhost/127.0.0.1`.
In case munin and munin-node are on different servers then munin should be able to read munin-node's `/server-status`.

If it doesn't hep check out the munin logs. Error should be definetly there.

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from localhost
   #Allow from all          
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jevgeni! I guess I'm a total noob, because I'm not sure what you mean by /server-status location... can you elaborate please? If it makes a difference, I have munin and munin-node running on the same server. Also, can you elaborate on what logs I should check? I've checked var/log/munin/munin-node.log, and there do not seem to be any error messages there. Just lines like this: `2013/03/01-06:40:01 CONNECT TCP Peer: "::ffff:127.0.0.1:48769" Local: "::ffff:127.0.0.1:4949"`

Comment: I'v updated the post. This is for example entry from my server's virtualhost. So the location is in inside virtualhost tag.

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks. That helps. It looks like the issue may be a rewrite rule in Drupal's .htaccess file which prevents munin being able to access /server-status. Am trying the solution posted at http://serverfault.com/questions/328851/apache-server-status-not-found-check-if-mod-status-is-enabled . Will post back if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Hm... still having trouble. I've fixed .htaccess, verified that I can access http://127.0.0.1/server-status, and checked apache logs which seem to show successful access attempts to /server-status... but Munin graphs are still blank. See my update to the original post. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well, looks like I didn't wait long enough after fixing the htaccess file... Munin graphs now seem to be working. Thanks for your help!